# DBFlow column types will not respect default values

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, dbflow

I am currently doing a migration of version in DBFlow to version 3.0.0-beta5 to 3.1.1 and I am having this problem right now:

```
Error:10:40:59.403 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:40:59.403 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:40:59.404 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:40:59.404 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:40:59.405 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:40:59.406 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:00.927 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:00.928 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:00.929 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:00.929 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:00.929 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:00.929 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signin\SignInFragment.java:36: error: package ph.paidup.databinding does not exist
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] import ph.paidup.databinding.ActivitySignInBinding;
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signin\SignInFragment.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] private ActivitySignInBinding mViewBinding;
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] symbol: class ActivitySignInBinding
10:41:01.529 [ERROR] [system.err] location: class SignInFragment
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signup\SignUpFragment.java:37: error: package ph.paidup.databinding does not exist
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] import ph.paidup.databinding.ActivitySignUpBinding;
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signup\SignUpFragment.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] private ActivitySignUpBinding mViewBinding;
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] symbol: class ActivitySignUpBinding
10:41:01.530 [ERROR] [system.err] location: class SignUpFragment
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signin\SignInFragment.java:49: error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] public class SignInFragment extends BaseFragment implements SignInContract.View {
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] C:\Users\Augusto\AndroidStudioProjects\AndroidPH-master\app\src\main\java\ph\paidup\view\session\signup\SignUpFragment.java:50: error: dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code.
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] public class SignUpFragment extends BaseFragment implements SignUpContract.View {
10:41:01.531 [ERROR] [system.err] ^
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:01.532 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: ==========
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] class com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.processor.validator.ColumnValidator:Primitive column types will not respect default values
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] ==========
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.PaidUpDatabasepaidup$Database' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: File for type 'com.raizlabs.android.dbflow.config.GeneratedDatabaseHolder' created in the last round will not be subject to annotation processing.
10:41:01.533 [ERROR] [system.err] warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[android.databinding.artifactType, android.databinding.printEncodedErrors, android.databinding.minApi, android.databinding.isTestVariant, android.databinding.enableDebugLogs, android.databinding.sdkDir, android.databinding.bindingBuildFolder, android.databinding.enableForTests, android.databinding.modulePackage, android.databinding.generationalFileOutDir, android.databinding.xmlOutDir]'
10:41:01.540 [ERROR] [system.err] 6 errors
10:41:01.540 [ERROR] [system.err] 14 warnings
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:41:01.565 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
10:41:01.566 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
10:41:01.567 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
10:41:01.568 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
10:41:01.569 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
10:41:01.570 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
10:41:01.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.572 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
10:41:01.573 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
10:41:01.574 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:48)
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:33)
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:104)
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:53)
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:38)
10:41:01.575 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
10:41:01.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
10:41:01.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:206)
10:41:01.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:187)
10:41:01.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:130)
10:41:01.576 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:49)
10:41:01.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
10:41:01.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
10:41:01.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
10:41:01.577 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
10:41:01.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
10:41:01.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
10:41:01.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] ... 78 more
10:41:01.578 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]
```

I already changed all the properties in order to get access to the variables. I hope you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 1):

This maybe because your getters for boolean values are not properly named. Change all `getBooleanValue()` format getters to `isBooleanValue()` format.

OR

add `@Table(useBooleanGetterSetters = true)` to your table.

This issue was reported before, you may check [this](https://github.com/Raizlabs/DBFlow/issues/976)

Comment: Thanks Aldrin. I already solved that issue. In my case there was a problem with an obsolete apt-get